# I'm getting too many requests (error: 429) when using the translator API in Flutter. How do i solve this

Tags: flutter, dart

**I translate the words in the text using onTap, but after a while I get an error because there are too many requests. How can I solve this? If I need to use the sleep function, how do I use it?**

"onTap: () {

```
                        appState.translator
                            .translate(e, from: 'tr', to: 'en')
                            .then((val) {
                           Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: val.text);
                           
                                                    
                       }); "
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you should make the `onTap` as `async` and `await` for your `Translator` , like this :

```
onTap: () async {

                       await appState.translator
                            .translate(e, from: 'tr', to: 'en')
                            .then((val) {
                           Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: val.text);
                           
                                                    
                       });
```